# How can I update my interpolation function to handle any value?

Tags: javascript, math, colors, graphics, interpolation

I'm working on an app that performs different interpolations for 3D LUT files. I'm taking it 1 step at a time (to learn, but also because I haven't found many resources online to help with this).

I've been making progress, but I've gotten stuck on one particular algorithm. Namely, I'm trying to implement tetrahedral interpolation for 3D .cube files.

Can someone show me what I'm missing and help me improve my code here?

So far I've been using the following resources to help me

**(See JavaScript code snippet or CodePen because I can't add links here apparently)**

And with these I've been able to make some great progress. So far, I'm able to handle the case where the size of the 3D LUT is of the form `(2^x)+1`, where x is an integer >= 1 (for example, with a standard `LUT_SIZE` of 17, 33, 65, etc.).

But I don't know how to handle the case where x is any other integer - for example, I have seen LUT files where the `LUT_SIZE` is 25, and I need to be able to handle that and any integer in the range `[2, 256]` according to the .cube spec.

The algorithm I'm using breaks down like this:

1. Find the MSB (most-significant-bits) of each color channel in the color of interest
2. In the huge cube of points, find the single sub-cube enclosing the color value of interest using the MSBs to index the LUT
3. From the vertices of the sub-cube, find the 6 tetrahedrons that further enclose the color. Based on the values of the color channels, choose 1 tetrahedron and return the interpolation
4. Scale the interpolated value so that its output matches the scale of the input

The problem is with step 1, because with what I've seen in the resources, calculating the MSBs only works when the points of the LUT are spaced `2^n` apart from each other, where n is an integer. So when trying to work with a `LUT_SIZE` of `25` and a bit depth of `8`, for example, n is equal to `3.415`, so I can't find the first `3.415` most-significant-bits of my color here.

And if I try to round n up or down, then I get incorrect vertices for the sub-cube. Using the same example, if `LUT_SIZE` is `25` and the bit depth is 8 still, with a color of `rgb(128, 128, 128)` then I get vertices in the range `[8, 8, 8] - [9, 9, 9]` when I should expect to get vertices in the range `[11, 11, 11] - [12, 12, 12]` as `rgb(128, 128, 128)` should lie halfway along each of the axes of the LUT cube.

Curiously, even with the wrong vertices being returned, the interpolation function still returns the correct value for my input colors. However, this is making me think that my problems run deeper and I made a mistake somewhere in my implementation.

The test data I'm using is also just a simple identity LUT that doesn't do any crazy transforms yet, so I can't say for certain how my code will work if I'm not certain on what its doing in the most simple of cases.

Can anyone help show me how to improve my process so I can handle an **arbitrary** `LUT_SIZE`? If I can just get the right vertices, then I think I will be on a great start.

Here is a link to my working CodePen where you can see the code and try different inputs: [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/redwhiteblack0/pen/VwRXRVW?editors=1011)

And here is a snippet that you can run here:

```js
// RESOURCES
/* 
1. Spec for 1D and 3D .cube files: [link](https://kono.phpage.fr/images/a/a1/Adobe-cube-lut-specification-1.0.pdf)
2. Paper explaining various interpolation algorithms: [link](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-95.pdf)
3. NVIDIA diagram on efficient tetrahedral interpolation: [link](https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/posters/2010/V01-Real-Time-Color-Space-Conversion-for-High-Resolution-Video.pdf)
*/


// Util Functions
// Multiply a vec by a scalar
const scalar_mult = (scalar, vec) => {
  return vec.map((val) => scalar * val);
};

// Perform standard vector addition on an array of vectors
// Ex. add_vecs([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) = [1 + 4 + 7, 2 + 5 + 8, 3 + 6 + 9] = [12, 15, 18]
// NOTE: Each vec must be the same length (not crucial here since all will be colors with vec3 in length)
const add_vecs = (vecs) => {
  const zero_vec = new Array(vecs[0].length).fill(0);

  return vecs.reduce((c, acc) => {
    return acc.map((val, idx) => val + c[idx]);
  }, zero_vec);
};

// Selectors & Event Listeners
const bitDepthSpEl = document.getElementById("bitDepthSp");
const bitDepthInEl = document.getElementById("bitDepthIn");

const colRInEl = document.getElementById("colRIn");
const colGInEl = document.getElementById("colGIn");
const colBInEl = document.getElementById("colBIn");

const lutSizeInEl = document.getElementById("lutSizeIn");

const calcBtnEl = document.getElementById("calcBtn");

const resultValEl = document.getElementById("resultVal");

bitDepthSpEl.textContent = bitDepthInEl.value;

bitDepthInEl.onchange = (e) => {
  bitDepthSpEl.textContent = bitDepthInEl.value;
};

calcBtnEl.onclick = () => {
  // Get constants
  // NOTE: Where N is used in the sources to specify the LUT_SIZE, we use "lut_size" to avoid confusion.
  // Lowercase "n" is different from the LUT_SIZE and represents the number of bits to shift each color channel
  // in order to find the MSB and efficiently index the table.
  // NOTE: To calculate the number n, use the fact that the LUT contains (2^(b-n))+1)^d entries
  // Where b = color channel bit depth, d = number of dimensions of LUT (always 3 in this example)
  // So we can simplify: (2^(b-n))+1 = lut_size, hence the value of n defined below
  // See: https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-95.pdf page 2
  const bit_depth = parseInt(bitDepthInEl.value) || 8;
  const lut_size = parseInt(lutSizeInEl.value) || 2;
  const n = Math.ceil(bit_depth - Math.log2(lut_size - 1));

  console.log("Bit depth chosen is: ", bit_depth);
  console.log(
    "Will need to shift by: ",
    n,
    " bits to find the MSBs for each color channel"
  );

  // Create test LUT data
  // Colors normalized in range of [0, 1]
  // Where 1 represents the max of the color channel at the specified bit depth
  // Ex. with bit_depth = 8, the color value 255 maps to 1. When bit_depth = 16, 255 maps to 0.003891 and 65535 maps to 1
  // Red changes most rapidly, then green, then blue
  // See: https://kono.phpage.fr/images/a/a1/Adobe-cube-lut-specification-1.0.pdf pages 9 and 16
  const lut_data = [];

  for (let b = 0; b < lut_size; b++) {
    for (let g = 0; g < lut_size; g++) {
      for (let r = 0; r < lut_size; r++) {
        // Simply the identity LUT here
        // Feel free to experiment here and catch any errors
        lut_data.push([r / lut_size, g / lut_size, b / lut_size]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Implement tetrahedral interpolation
  // Steps:
  //    1. Get MSB (most-significant-bits) of each color channel
  //    2. Find the vertices of the enclosing sub-cube (each v[i] will be in the range [0, lut_size - 1])
  //    3. Find the LUT values at each of the 6 tetrahedron vertices inside of the sub-cube and take the weighted sum to calculate the interpolated value for each color channel
  //    4. Re-scale the interpolated value to output to RGB
  // See: https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/posters/2010/V01-Real-Time-Color-Space-Conversion-for-High-Resolution-Video.pdf
  const interpolateColor = (px) => {
    const [r, g, b] = px;

    // STEP 1. Get MSB of each color channel
    // See: https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-95.pdf page 3
    const r_u = r >> n;
    const g_u = g >> n;
    const b_u = b >> n;

    const px_msb = [r_u, g_u, b_u];

    // STEP 2. Calculate vertices of enclosing sub-cube
    // See: https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-95.pdf page 3
    const p1 = [r_u, g_u, b_u];
    const p2 = [r_u, g_u, b_u + 1];
    const p3 = [r_u, g_u + 1, b_u];
    const p4 = [r_u, g_u + 1, b_u + 1];
    const p5 = [r_u + 1, g_u, b_u];
    const p6 = [r_u + 1, g_u, b_u + 1];
    const p7 = [r_u + 1, g_u + 1, b_u];
    const p8 = [r_u + 1, g_u + 1, b_u + 1];

    console.log("Cube Vertices: ", p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8);

    // Get LUT values from vertices of enclosing sub-cube
    const v_to_lut_vals = (v) => {
      // Get index inside of LUT data
      // See: https://kono.phpage.fr/images/a/a1/Adobe-cube-lut-specification-1.0.pdf page 9
      const lut_idx = v[0] + lut_size * v[1] + lut_size * lut_size * v[2];

      return lut_data[lut_idx];
    };

    // Use these LUT values for each of the vertices of the tetrahedrons
    const l1 = v_to_lut_vals(p1);
    const l2 = v_to_lut_vals(p2);
    const l3 = v_to_lut_vals(p3);
    const l4 = v_to_lut_vals(p4);
    const l5 = v_to_lut_vals(p5);
    const l6 = v_to_lut_vals(p6);
    const l7 = v_to_lut_vals(p7);
    const l8 = v_to_lut_vals(p8);

    console.log("LUT values at vertices: ", l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8);

    // STEP 3. Interpolate tetrahedrons
    // See: https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/posters/2010/V01-Real-Time-Color-Space-Conversion-for-High-Resolution-Video.pdf
    const t1 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - g - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(g - b, l3),
      scalar_mult(b - r, l4),
      scalar_mult(r, l8)
    ]);

    const t2 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - b - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(b - r, l2),
      scalar_mult(r - g, l6),
      scalar_mult(g, l8)
    ]);

    const t3 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - b - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(b - g, l2),
      scalar_mult(g - r, l4),
      scalar_mult(r, l8)
    ]);

    const t4 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - r - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(r - g, l5),
      scalar_mult(g - b, l7),
      scalar_mult(b, l8)
    ]);

    const t5 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - g - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(g - r, l3),
      scalar_mult(r - b, l7),
      scalar_mult(b, l8)
    ]);

    const t6 = add_vecs([
      scalar_mult(1 - r - 1, l1),
      scalar_mult(r - b, l5),
      scalar_mult(b - g, l6),
      scalar_mult(g, l8)
    ]);

    console.log("Interpolations Found: ", t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);

    // STEP 4. Re-scale to proper size to undo normalizing step when creating the LUT data
    const rescale = (vec) => {
      return scalar_mult(lut_size, vec);
    };

    let interpolated;

    // Choose interpolation val based on condition
    if (g >= b && b >= r) {
      interpolated = rescale(t1);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t1]: ", interpolated);
    } else if (b > r && r > g) {
      interpolated = rescale(t2);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t2]: ", interpolated);
    } else if (b > g && g >= r) {
      interpolated = rescale(t3);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t3]: ", interpolated);
    } else if (r >= g && g > b) {
      interpolated = rescale(t4);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t4]: ", interpolated);
    } else if (g > r && r >= b) {
      interpolated = rescale(t5);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t5]: ", interpolated);
    } else if (r >= b && b >= g) {
      interpolated = rescale(t6);
      console.log("Chose interpolation [t6]: ", interpolated);
    }

    // Return rounded interpolated value
    return interpolated.map((col) => Math.round(col));
  };

  // Handle user input and display result
  const selected_r = parseInt(colRInEl.value);
  const selected_g = parseInt(colGInEl.value);
  const selected_b = parseInt(colBInEl.value);

  const interpolated = interpolateColor([selected_r, selected_g, selected_b]);

  const clamp = (col) => {
    return Math.min(col, 255);
  };

  resultValEl.textContent = `rgb(${interpolated[0]}, ${interpolated[1]}, ${interpolated[2]})`;
  resultValEl.style.borderBottom = `2px solid rgb(${clamp(
    interpolated[0]
  )}, ${clamp(interpolated[1])}, ${clamp(interpolated[2])})`;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <p>Pick <span id="bitDepthSp"></span>-bit RGB Color</p>
    <section class="colors section">
      <div>
        <label for="">r: </label>
        <input id="colRIn" type="number" min="0" max="65535" step="1" value="0">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="">g: </label>
        <input id="colGIn" type="number" min="0" max="65535" step="1" value="0">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="">b: </label>
        <input id="colBIn" type="number" min="0" max="65535" step="1" value="0">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section">
      <label for="">LUT Size</label>
      <!-- Max 3D LUT size for .cube files as defined in the spec is 256 -->
      <input id="lutSizeIn" type="number" min="2" , max="256" value="17">
    </section>
    <section class="section">
      <label for="">Bit Depth</label>
      <!-- Max 3D LUT size for .cube files as defined in the spec is 256 -->
      <select id="bitDepthIn" value="8">
        <option name="16" value="16">16</option>
        <option name="12" value="12">12</option>
        <option name="10" value="10">10</option>
        <option name="8" value="8" selected>8</option>
        <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
        <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section class="section">
      <button id="calcBtn">Calculate Interpolation</button>
    </section>
    <section id="result section">
      <p id="resultVal"></p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or additional resources will be very appreciated. Thanks!